# Assign number to array members and choose the highest

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form in VBA that allows user to select multiple options (approx. 1-10 items). All the selected members are stored in an array that can be of different size. I am looking for a way to assign to all the items that were selected a numerical value (given by existing hierarchy) and then being able to select the item with the highest value. Is there any way how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 2 dimensional array instead of a 1 dimensional.

Eg if your array looked like

```
Dim MyArr(2) As Variant
MyArr(0) = "Member1"
MyArr(1) = "Member2"
MyArr(2) = "Member3"
```

Make it 2 dimensional to assign a numerical value for each member

```
Dim MyArr(2, 1) As Variant

MyArr(0, 0) = "Member1"
MyArr(0, 1) = 1

MyArr(1, 0) = "Member2"
MyArr(1, 1) = 2

MyArr(2, 0) = "Member3"
MyArr(2, 1) = 3
```

[image]

---

*(Edit according comments)*

Use 2 distinct arrays for members and values to be able to find the maximum value easier using the `WorksheetFunction`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim MyArrMembers(2) As String
    Dim MyArrValues(2) As Long

    MyArrMembers(0) = "Member1"
    MyArrValues(0) = 1

    MyArrMembers(1) = "Member2"
    MyArrValues(1) = 100

    MyArrMembers(2) = "Member3"
    MyArrValues(2) = 3

    'find max value
    Dim MaxVal As Long
    MaxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MyArrValues)

    'locate max value
    Dim ArrIndex As Long
    ArrIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MaxVal, MyArrValues, 0) - 1

    'output member name
    Debug.Print MyArrMembers(ArrIndex) 'returns Member2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the first part of my problem but am I then able to loop through the 2nd array dimension, select the highest value and print out the respective value from the first dimension?

Comment: @FAB there is. You can use `WorksheetFunction.Max()` on a one dimensional array. You just need to split it into 2 arrays.